# Number of points on triangle or its boundary Queries.

Tags: algorithms

We are given **P** 2-D points (x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3),....(xP,yP).

There are total **M** number of Queries. Each query is in the form of a triplet.The format of each query is :

> (a b d)

Let **T** be a triangle with vertices X(a+d,b),Y(a,b),Z(a,b+d).

For each of the **M Queries**, we have to return how many of the given points lie inside or on the boundary of triangle.

**Example**

P=5, M=3

The points(xi,yi) are :

```
1 3

1 5

3 6

4 4

2 6
```

The M Queries (format (a,b,d))  are:

> 1 5 3
>
> 1 5 4
>
> 1 1 1
>
> Answer for above three queries are 3,3,0 respectively.

I tried to solve this problem using simple naive approach.But the constraints for the problem is indeed very large and are follows:

> 1 ≤ P ≤ 300000    1 ≤ M ≤ 200000
>
> 1 ≤ xi, yi ≤ 300000
>
> 1 ≤ a, b, d ≤ 300000

The Time Limit for this problem is just `1 Second`.

How can i solve this problem within the given time-limit?